# Azure App Service - WEBSITE_HEALTHCHECK_MAXPINGFAILURES and time of Load Balancing

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-appservice

### Description

> The required number of failed requests for an instance to be deemed unhealthy and removed from the load balancer. For example, when set to 2, your instances will be removed after 2 failed pings. (Default value is 10)

Here is the [description](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/monitor-instances-health-check#:%7E:text=The%20required%20number%20of%20failed%20requests%20for%20an%20instance%20to%20be%20deemed%20unhealthy%20and%20removed%20from%20the%20load%20balancer) for WEBSITE_HEALTHCHECK_MAXPINGFAILURES. **What is the difference between WEBSITE_HEALTHCHECK_MAXPINGFAILURES and the Load Balancing in the picture below?**

I found when I change Load Balancing to 5, the value of WEBSITE_HEALTHCHECK_MAXPINGFAILURES will be changed to 5.

[image]

### Test

**Localhost will send two requests in one minute.**

- Before enabling Health Check, there is no any request.
- After enabling Health Check, two requests will be received in every minute for every instance.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference. The portal offers a better UI experience for setting `WEBSITE_HEALTHCHECK_MAXPINGFAILURES`. Both represent the total amount of time in minutes of getting failed pings before App Service determines it is unhealthy and removes it, because:

> Health check pings this path on all instances of your App Service app at **1-minute intervals**.

Comment: Forgot to say, after I test. 127.0.0.1 will send two request in one minute

Comment: @kyakya how many instances does your web app have, 2?

Comment: 2 request every instance. I have tested it from 1 to 3 instance.

Comment: @kyakya I am not sure why there are 2 requests to every instance but it doesn't affect the outcome. It might be that they decided that sending 2 pings is more reliable than sending 1 but it is an implementation detail.

Comment: @kyakya feel free to [accept any answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it was of any help to you. If it isn't, feel free to ask for details.